# Outputting an email attachment from Microsoft Graph into a file on disk

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I have retrieved some attachments from an email object using Microsoft Graph's REST API thus:

```
$Header = Get-Header -theRequest $Credential
$restUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$UserPrincipalName/messages/$messageId/attachments"
$emailAttachmentResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $restUrl -Headers $Header -Method Get -ContentType "application/json"
```

I can [then] successfully loop through these attachment results thus:

```
foreach($att in $emailAttachmentResult.value)
{
    $attName = $att.Name
    Write-Output $attName  # Successfully displays the name of the attachment
}
```

What I want to do next is to output the content of this attachment to a file on disk.  That's the part where I am getting stuck.

I have tried all manner of convoluted things - here is my latest attempt [which fails - it just creates files of zero length]:

```
$theFolderToUse = "C:\temp"
$filename = (Join-Path $theFolderToUse $att.Name.ToString())
[System.IO.File]::Create($filename)
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($filename, $att.ContentBytes)
```

I have also tried this:

```
$attachmentContent = $att.ContentBytes
$fiFile = New-Object System.IO.FileStream((Join-Path $theFolderToUse $att.Name.ToString()), [System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
$fiFile.Write($attachmentContent, 0, $attachmentContent.length)
```

But this also outputs zero length files.

I have further tried converting the variable:

```
$att.ContentBytes
```

to byte arrays thus:

```
$converter = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode
$byteArray = $converter.GetBytes($attachmentContent);
$fiFile = New-Object System.IO.FileStream((Join-Path $theFolderToUse $att.Name.ToString()), [System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
$fiFile.Write($byteArray, 0, $byteArray.length)
```

This outputs files with content but in an unreadable format.  Somehow the data that is in:

```
$att.ContentBytes
```

Does not make it through the conversion processes back and forth such that it actually reconstitutes the original file attachment...

Can anyone suggest how to get:

```
$att.ContentBytes
```

Into a file on disk?  Bear in mind that the attachments represented include binary files like PDF's and Excel Spreadsheets.

Thanks heaps all,

David :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That ContentBytes is encoded in Base64 so you first need to convert that to a Byte Array and then write that Byte array to a file eg

```
    $downloadDirectory = "c:\temp"
    foreach($att in $emailAttachmentResult.value)
    {
        $fiFile = new-object System.IO.FileStream(($downloadDirectory  + "\" + $att.Name.ToString()), [System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
        $attachBytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($att.ContentBytes)   
        $fiFile.Write($attachBytes, 0, $attachBytes.Length)
        $fiFile.Close()
    }
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks heaps mate... that's got it working! :-)

Comment: This also seems to be needed for these extensions: jpg, jpeg, gif, png, pdf